# How do I SVN-commit multiple git-svn repositories simultaneously?

Tags: git, git-svn

I work at a company that tracks what could be viewed as multiple projects under one SVN repository.  Therefore, when I git-svn cloned said repository, I did it into multiple git-svn repositories.  However, sometimes it would be better to SVN-commit a single logical change that spans multiple projects.  Is there a way to do this?

For example, given the git-svn repositories:

- project-a => svn://svn.server/project-a
- project-b => svn://svn.server/project-b

I would like to be able to do `git svn dcommit-simultaneously project-a project-b` or something and have it commit only once to SVN.

Comment: Are repositories contents the same? If not, I doubt that you can do that even with pure Git repositories.

Comment: @Dmitry They're mapped to different SVN paths, so no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run "svn info $project_url" for each project.  If the reported "Repository Root" is the same for each, then you can "git svn clone $repo_root" and use that to make an atomic commit across the projects.  Otherwise, it's not possible to make an atomic commit across repositories, even natively with subversion.

Comment: So there's no way to do it using two existing git-svn clones that already have changes in them (which I feel like should be possible in theory)?

Comment: Nope, can't be done.  git commands (unlike svn commands) operate on exactly one local repository.  you're trying to operate on two local repositories; I can't think of any git command that functions like that.